# Proof that $\sup\{\mathcal M(y)| y\le x\}$ is not primitive recursive.

Tags: computability

Let $f$ be a function that is recursive but not primitive recursive, and let $\mathcal M$ be a Turing machine which computes $f$.  I am trying to prove that the function

$$ g(x) = \sup\{\mathcal M(y)|y\le x\} $$

is not primitive recursive.  I know that a function is primitive recursive if and only if its graph is PR and is bounded by a PR function.  Also I know that if a function is increasing then it is PR if and only if its image is PR.

I've mostly tried proof by contradiction: Assume $g$ is PR and show that $f$ is PR.  It seems like $im(f)=im(g)$, and clearly $g$ is increasing.  So therefore $im(f)=im(g)$ is PR.  But we cannot yet conclude that $f$ is PR.  Certainly also $f\le g$ and we are assuming that $g$ is PR, so we only need to show that the graph of $f$ is PR.  But I don't see a way to prove that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't true in general. What if $ran(f)$ is bounded? In this case $g$ is eventually constant, and every eventually constant function is PR.

(To see that there are recursive non-PR functions with bounded range, let $\mathscr{H}=(h_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ be the standard enumeration of PR functions and consider the function $$f(x)=\begin{cases}
1 & \mbox{ if }h_x(x)=0\\
0 & \mbox{ otherwise}.
\end{cases}$$ This $f$ is clearly not PR and has bounded range, and $f$ is recursive since the PR functions are total and our enumeration of PR functions $\mathscr{H}$ was "reasonable." More generally, for any reasonably-indexable class of total recursive functions there will be total recursive bounded functions not in that class by the same argument.)

Comment: Ah, I realized I neglected a part of what the problem should be -- rather than $\sup\{\mathcal M(y)| y\le x\}$ it should instead be the sup over the running time of the machine $\sup\{T_{\mathcal M}|y\le x\}$.